# SAS Data Conversion

Tags: sas

Can someone help translate this PROC SQL code to a Data Step?  I am hoping that the Data Step will be much faster.  I generated this code from SAS-EG so I am not proficient enough yet.

Thanks
Jeff

```
PROC SQL;
  CREATE TABLE WORK.'APPAREL NEWNESS 01'n AS 
  SELECT DISTINCT t2.outletfamily AS outletfamily, 
      t2.itemid, 
      t2.itemnumberunsuppressed AS itemnumber_unsuppressed, 
      t2.ppmonth, 
      /* Dollars */
        (SUM(t2.totalvalue)) FORMAT=DOLLAR20. AS Dollars, 
      /* Units */
        (SUM(t2.unitssold)) FORMAT=COMMA20. AS Units, 
      /* Proj Dollars */
        (SUM(t2.proj_totalvalue)) FORMAT=DOLLAR20. AS 'Proj Dollars'n, 
      /* Proj Units */
        (SUM(t2.proj_unitssold)) FORMAT=COMMA20. AS 'Proj Units'n
  FROM APLSWP.vw_aplmlwk_fact_nat_nc_uns t2
  GROUP BY t2.outletfamily,
           t2.itemid,
           t2.itemnumberunsuppressed,
           t2.ppmonth;
  QUIT;
```

Comment: A data step will only be able to group items if the data is already sorted. Is that the case?

Comment: Could I translate your question as "Is there a tranditional SAS programming technique that does this faster than SQL"?

Comment: Jeff, I suggest that you use another title for this question: rewriting SQL statement into a SAS procedure while seeking a better performance has little to do with 'SAS Data Conversion'. A more fitted title might attract a broader audience.

Comment: What is the library statement that defines `APLSWP` ?

Answer (score 2):

- The functionality of `GROUP BY` and `SUM` are available in `proc summary` or in a simlar, yet much richer `proc means`. Unfortunately I do not have a SAS licence available so can't provide you with a code. Look for an example of your problem solved in `proc means` [here](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/proc/61895/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a002473539.htm).
- When using `GROUP BY var1, var2, var3, var4`, the procedure produces distinct combinations of values of var1, var2, var3 and var4. The keyword `DISTINCT` is unnecessary though.
- The performance could be affected by where the data resides vs. where you run the query. If the query is in an external database (e.g. Oracle) you might benefit from looking at so-called "pass-through facility". This allow SAS code run directly in the DB and utilize its indexes, statistics and all the DB features that make databases powerful.

Comment: You can access SAS via SAS Academics on Demand - Independent learner, no need to be affiliated with academia, the only limitation is no commercial usage. It is fully hosted on the cloud so basically only need to log in when you want to access it.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using PROC MEANS instead. Without sample data I can't be sure this is exactly what you're looking for but should get you close:

```
  proc means data=APLSWP.vw_aplmlwk_fact_nat_nc_uns noprint nway;
  *CLASS = grouping variables;
  class outletfamily itemid itemnumberunsuppressed ppmonth;
  *VAR = list of variables to analyze (optional);
  var totalValue UnitSold Proj_Total_value proj_unitssold;
  *create output data set;
  output out=want 
    /*list of summary statistics to save*/
    sum(totalValue) = dollars 
    sum(UnitSold) = units 
    sum(Proj_Total_value) = 'Proj Dollars'n 
    sum(proj_unitssold) = 'Proj Units'n;
  run;
```

Comment: This looks as a correct solution; you can further show the values with $ or comma as decimal separator using `FORMAT` clause.